# What to do when Http Post was completed successfully and while waiting for response internet connectivity lost?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, android-asynctask

I am sending  data to server by using HTTP post and successfully it fired at the server. Now In between sending the  data and waiting for server response, suddenly Due to network problem my android device gets internet connection lost.
In device m able to show  an alert dialog of connection lost, but at server side the data was already processed and it was updated in database ie MySQL server   But my android device  does not know this bcoz till  it did not get any  response from server. How to resolve it.

Whether it could be done on server side or in android app and How?

How server would know that android phone is not getting  the response till now ?

Any Idea .. Waiting for the answer???

Comment: did you get exception when you lost connectivity?

Comment: Dont Go for Exception.. I have dialog for connectivity lost.

Comment: what happened when you lost connectivity in between when you were posting(full data not posted).

Comment: use push notification when your server receives full data and it is processed. so when you get back the connectivity you receive the notification.

Comment: Just read the question again.. Everything is fine . Post data is successful and it also send the response. Problem Is before response going to android mobile connection lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each request which is sent from device to server you should generate unique ID (check [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for example)

then you send request with this id to server, if connection lost - trying to re-send with the same ID

on server side you have to implement check: if the query with ID was processed/inprocess/new

Comment: Its Ok .. First Time Request+Id was successfully fired. So Resend the req create confusion on server side. 
   
   So again my quest for duplicate request?
 How does the server detect repeat requests from the client when the server successfully received the first request?

Comment: @subhalaxminayak check my 3rd sentence in answer

Comment: If it check the request it will find that request all ready processed. than It will return Again the same response for that particular Id or this can be  handled simply by returning the same response  to the client. M i right??

Comment: @subhalaxminayak right, so you need somehow emulate proper answer, either by storing full answer in db during real processing, or just output "ok" - if it is enough for you mobile application

Answer (score 3):

GUID:Globally Unique Identifier.

It is created automatically.
GUIDs are usually stored as 128-bit values, and are commonly displayed as 32 hexadecimal digits with groups separated by hyphens,
 such as `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`
GUIDs generated from random numbers sometimes contain 6 fixed bits saying they are random and 122 random bits; the total number of unique such GUIDs is 2122 or 5.3×1036.

This number is so large that the probability of the same number being generated randomly twice is negligible; 
however other GUID versions have different uniqueness properties and probabilities, ranging from guaranteed uniqueness to likely non-uniqueness. Assuming uniform probability for simplicity, the probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million GUIDs.